# How to do error handling when including other 3rd party libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I've added a 3rd party open source library to my php app. (phpseclib)
I've wrapped all my calls to their methods with try / catch blocks and I'm handling all errors so that I handle errors gracefully.

However, because the 3rd party library doesn't have baked in error handling, when it dies, I get a php error from it + another codeigniter message that I'm throwing when I, let's say, try to connect to a device and it fails.

Aside from changing the library to include some error handling, I just want to make sure that there's nothing I can do to prevent these "unhandled" messages from appearing to the end user...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own error handler with [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and ignore and/or handle errors according to their level.

Comment: would this be defined in the 3rd party library or in my ci code that calls the lib?

Comment: @dot You could do it both ways but I would suggest to only change your own code. When you want to add it to your third-party library, you should fork that project and issue a pull request after your changes so that it can be included in the official version.

Answer (score 0):

Probably:

```
// Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: You don't want to turn off error reporting, what you want to do it hide error messages instead. If you app breaks or has an error you will not know otherwise.